# Tkinter ttk not updating until I unfocus and refocus or resize the window

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to make a frame that the user can scale with their mouse.

I have code that is supposed to make a frames x size follow the mouse while my mouse is down. My resize code is running whenever I move my mouse while its down but the frame doesn't update until I de focus and refocus or resize the window.

My code is

```
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
from tkinter import N, E, S, W

window = ThemedTk(theme="equilux")
window.resizable(height = None, width = None)
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

class EventManager():
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = {}
        self.eventsHandler = {}
        self.eventHandlerCreater = lambda eventName: window.bind(eventName, lambda e: [i(e) for i in self.events[eventName]])
    def registerEvent(self, event, function):
        if self.events.get(event, None) is None:
            self.events[event] = []
            self.eventsHandler[event] = self.eventHandlerCreater(event)
        self.events[event].append(function)

class Widget():
    def __init__(self, eventManager: EventManager):
        self.width = 500
        self.events = eventManager
        self.events.registerEvent("<B1-Motion>", self.resize)
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(window, width=self.width)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

    def resize(self, event):
        x = event.x
        print("a")
        if True: #(x - self.width) + 100 > 0:
            self.width = x
        print(self.width)
 
    def update(self):
        self.frame.config(width=self.width)
        print("Update")

man = EventManager()
wid = Widget(man)

while True:
    wid.update()
    window.update()
    window.update_idletasks()
```

Comment: If you add `window.grid_propagate(0)`, then the resize of the frame will follow the mouse.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you soo much that worked. If you make it a answer than I can mark it correct